# SOLVED function returns nothing with if-else statements

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return, return-type

Turns out I just didn't know how return in fuctions work.
Thanks for your help!

I'm trying to use beautiful soup to find specific links on a list of websites.
I try to find

1. href url that contain a keyword
2. anchors that contain the keyword
3. if the page doesn't contain keyword print "not found".

The idea is for the function to return either a URL or a "not found"

I've built the code with beautifulsoup and built if-else statements
so the function returns variable a that is either a link or a "not found"
It works with printing the different results along the way, but the function return is empty.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
import re
import ssl

#function to parse a website from a url and find the links that contain the content about transparency.

def transp_url(url):
    #hearders because some pages return 403 error
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

    #SSL certificate error with some pages, thus adding this:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

    req = Request(url, headers=hdr)
    html_page = urlopen(req)
    global a
    #find one href link URL that contains "transpar"
    #problem with casing doesn't recognise uper or lower.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
    link = soup.select_one("a[href*=transpar]")
    if link:
        #print("link found")
        a = link['href']
        #print(a)

    else:
    #get the link of the transparence page based on anchor.
    #problem with casing doesn't recognise uper or lower.
        link2 = soup.find("a", string=re.compile("Transpar"))
        if link2:
            #print("link found")
            a = link2['href']
            #print(a)
        else: 
            link3 = soup.find("a", string=re.compile("transpar"))
            if link3:
                #print("link found")
                a = link3['href']
                #print(a)
            else:
                #print("No Transparency page")            
                a = "No Transparency page"
                #print(a)
    return a

transp_url('https://www.vivaqua.be/fr/')
```

Comment: I see you have posted a function which has a `return a` at the end. Can you show how you call this function?

Comment: I just call the function in the code for testing purposes at the moment like this:
transp_url('https://www.vivaqua.be/fr/')

Comment: Ok, but how can you tell that `"the function return is empty"`?

Comment: When I execute in terminal with "python3 transp_url.py" I'm expecting to see a link as response, instead it returns nothing

Comment: You will need to eventually print something to see anything on the terminal. Did you mean: `print(transp_url('vivaqua.be/fr/'))`?

Comment: Oh ok! I thought the return in function would print something in terminal. Great news my function works then haha! Thanks a million!!